# How do I refer to the parameter passed to javascript in html?

Tags: javascript, html

When I call the script via

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
        src="include/javascript/test_something.js?v=1128557"></script>
```

how do I refer to the variable V passed in the html?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: I updated my post, the html got parsed when I posted the code.

Comment: what server side technology are you using?

Comment: Where is this value (1128557) coming from?

Comment: The V value is returned from php as the userID of the current user. So say If I wanted a dynamic error box with the userID for troubleshooting purposes. This part I have completed. I'm looking for an alternative method to using an onload with the function variable to pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most simple way would be to use a server side technology. This is in php.

```
<?php
$v=1128557;
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
   //This will make this value available to javascript too
    var val=<?php=$v?>;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" 
        src="include/javascript/test_something.js?v=<?php=$v?>"></script>

...
...
...
<div id='baba<?php=$v?>'>
 ...
 ...
</div>
```

This will be translated to the following html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   //This will make this value available to javascript too
    var val=1128557;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" 
        src="include/javascript/test_something.js?v=1128557"></script>

...
...
...
<div id='baba1128557'>
 ...
 ...
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think you've read the question properly. We are looking for a way to find out the options passed to the javascript, not the server-side script

Comment: @Milad Naseri I read and understood the question. I believe my solution is the right one (at least it is the simplest one). He knows the value up front, why would he need to implement all those hoops people are suggesting when and easy and simp[le solution exists to repeat various part in an html page?

Comment: You might be right, but that's just assumptions. Based on the comments, I'd say we don't have that option. And even if we did, a lazily loaded JavaScript might need to access that data later on. Or even, the JavaScript in question might be lazily loaded by another script from the client side.

Comment: @Milad Naseri :-D  check my answer, edited to answer your latest concern. b.t.w if you think about it, my assumption is pretty good. I can't think on an example server side wont have access to this...

Comment: Yeah, can't argue with that. You're on with it. +1 for the correctness of your answer and reasonable assumptions when the asking person wasn't kind enough to provide them, and also putting up with my stubbornness :-D

Comment: @Milad Naseri - Nonsense, we learn by discussions, I thank you for making me think.

Comment: I keep forgetting the global scope of javascript, this indeed works as a method to return the value of V. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Get it from the `src` attribute of the last script element in your page:

```
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
var src = scripts[scripts.length - 1].src;
var v = null;
if (/\?v=(.+)$/.test(src)){
    v = RegExp.$1;
}
```

Comment: Why the last script element? :-)

Comment: Yeah, why the last? I think running the code I've written above on all the script elements SRCs instead of the `window.location.href` will do the trick.

Comment: Because, when the script executes, its element is the last element on the page. Of course if you wait until the page has loaded, you've made your job a lot harder. I was going to edit my answer to include a note explaining that, but I'm typing on my phone and you got your comments in quicker than I could edit my answer.

Comment: Why a regexp when you can use a simple `split` on `"?v="`

Answer (score 1):

If it's the first script tag on the page, you can do something like:

```
var thescripttag = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
var v = thescripttag[0].src.replace(/^[^\?]+\??/,''); //gets everything after the '?'
```

If it's not the first script tag, you can change [0] to be whichever one it is, or try assigning an id to the script tag (untested).

Answer (score 0):

You can find the appropriate script tag by looking for the desired filename and get the parameters off that `.src` URL.

```
function findScriptParams(fname) {
    fname = "/" + fname + "?";
    var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
    for (var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) {
        var pos = scripts[i].src.indexOf(fname);
        if (pos != -1) {
            return(scripts[i].src.substr(pos + fname.length));
        }
    }
}
```

And then you would invoke it like this:

```
var params = findScriptParams("test_something.js");
if (params) {
     // process the params here
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should do the following:

```
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
var data = {};
for (var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i ++) {
    if (!scripts[i].src) {
        continue;
    }
    var value = scripts[i]..substring(scripts[i].indexOf('?') + 1);
    var params = value.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i ++) {
        params[i] = params[i].split('=');
        data[params[i][0]] = params[i][1];
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: Just incorporated some of the tips from others, and added them to my own answer.

Answer (score -1):

JavaScript only has access to URL data for the page it's being *executed* on via `window.location`. It does not have access to any HTTP request variables passed to the javascript file itself unless the web server explicitly serializes it to JavaScript in the output.

One hack/workaround would be to find the script tag, get the `src` attribute, parse the URL and extract the GET parameters you need.

```
function getParamsFor(script) {
    var params, anchor, paramArray, keyVal, tag, scripts;

    scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");

    // Make sure [].filter exists beforehand
    tag = Array.prototype.filter.call(scripts, function (e) { 
        return e.src.indexOf(script) > -1;
    })[0];

    if (tag) {
        anchor = document.createElement("a");
        anchor.href = tag.src;

        paramArray = anchor.search.substring(1).split('&');
        params = {};

        for(var i = 0; i < paramArray.length; i++) {
           keyVal = paramArray[i].split('=');
           params[unescape(keyVal[0])] = (typeof keyVal[1] != "undefined") ? unescape(keyVal[1]) : keyVal[1];
        }

        return params;
    }
}

var o = getParamsFor("test_something.js");
o.v; // 112..
```

Comment: This code is a bit lengthy but clearly does the job as well. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Change it to

```
<script type="text/javascript"  
        src="include/javascript/test_something.php?v=1128557" />
```

Then create the script `test_something.php` to be

```
<?php
echo "var queryString='" . $_SERVER[`QUERY_STRING] . "'\n;";
?>
... rest of javascript here
```

You can even perform error checking/parsing of the query string using PHP or just get Javascript to do this.